# Convert duration like "4d 5hours 8mins" to seconds

Tags: javascript

I'm not sure how I would do something like this.

For example, you **input** `4d 5hours 8mins` and in **return** would result with `364080`.

The input could have many possible combos like "4 days" or "4days" instead of "4d" etc.

I haven't tried anything. I am new to JS and searched for the answers but haven't found any that work for me.

Comment: Well defined, but sample code is missing (post code even if it does not work, so that we can help out better)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in three steps:

- `.replace()` -- remove space between amount and unit
- `.split()` -- split on spaces
- `.reduce()` -- reduce amount and unit to seconds

Working code with examples:

```js
[
  '4days 5hours 8mins',
  '4days 5hours 8mins 20secs',
  '14 days 15 hours 18 mins',
  '4D 5 Hours 8M'
].forEach(str => {
  let time = str
    .replace(/(\d) *([a-z])[a-z]*/gi, '$1$2')  // remove space between amount and unit
    .split(/ +/)  // split on space
    .reduce((sum, val) => { // reduce amount and unit to seconds
      let m = val.match(/^([^a-z]+)(.*)/i);
      if(m) {
        let amount = Number(m[1]);
        let unit = m[2]?.toLowerCase();
        if(unit === 'd') {
          sum += amount * 60 * 60 * 24;
        } else if(unit === 'h') {
          sum += amount * 60 * 60;
        } else if(unit === 'm') {
          sum += amount * 60;
        } else if(unit === 's') {
          sum += amount;
        }
      }
      return sum;
    }, 0);
  console.log(str, ' ==> ' , time, ' seconds');
});
```

Output:

```
4days 5hours 8mins  ==>  364080  seconds
4days 5hours 8mins 20secs  ==>  364100  seconds
14 days 15 hours 18 mins  ==>  1264680  seconds
4D 5 Hours 8M  ==>  364080  seconds
```